# weapon_term helper of weapon system on "thirdperson" target (cryengine)

Tags: cryengine

I just walked through the "SCAR.xml" weapon item example, it's fantastic easy to use as a reference for making a new weapon. There is a question confusing me about  block.

```
    <accessories>
       <accessory name="Silencer">
          ...
          <muzzleflash>
             <firstperson effect="weapon_fx.scar.muzzle_flash.muzzle_flash_silenced_fp" helper="muzzle_flash_effect" time="0.1" />
             <thirdperson effect="weapon_fx.scar.muzzle_flash.muzzle_flash_silenced_tp" helper="weapon_term" time="0.1" />
          </muzzleflash>
          ...
       </accessory>
    </accessories>
```

For "**muzzle_flash_effect**" helper, it makes sense that an attachment of the "firstperson" target has been defined in  block. My confusing question is that "**weapon_term**" helper linking to the second element of  block has never been defined, and the thirdperson target (static mesh) doesn't contain such a bone named "weapon_term" either, it doesn't make sense how the effect is linked to the "non-existing" helper?

Thanks for help!

/Edgar

Answer (score 0):

Solution: create dummy objects (in 3ds Max, locators for Maya) as stand ins for weapon attachments in Sandbox.

The following is a list of helpers from the Crysis game:

```
    Attachment_top (for attachments at the top of the weapon)
    Attachment_bottom (for attachments at the bottom of the weapon)
    Attachment_side (for attachments at the side of the weapon)
    Magazine (for magazine only)
    Shells (for shells ejecting)
    Silencer_attach (for a silencer at the front of the weapon)
    Weapon_term (for muzzelflashes only)
    grenade_term (for muzzelflashes for grenade launchers)
```

[Third-Person Weapons](https://docs.cryengine.com/display/SDKDOC2/Third-Person+Weapons).

/Edgar